# Is there a way to append or union two constraint streams?

Tags: optaplanner

I have a use case where I have to merge two constraint streams into a single constraint stream. In SQL, this would be something like `UNION ALL`. However, I can't seem to find a way to do so.

While my exact usecase is too large to be practical here, I can try to explain here. We have a portfolio of spectrum rights, representing the exclusive right to use a specific span of radio spectrum in a specific geographic area:

```
public class SpectrumRight {
   private int geometryId;
   private int lowerFrequency;
   private int upperFrequency;
   ...
}
```

We also have problem facts representing our existing spectrum rights portfolio

```
...
@ProblemFactCollectionProperty
public List<SpectrumRight> existingPortfolio;
...
```

Then we also have a collection of spectrum rights that are up for auction, packaged into a "CallSign" which is basically just a prepackaged collection of spectrum rights (may have different frequencies or different geographic areas):

```
@PlanningEntity
public class AuctionLicense {
    @PlanningId
    private String callSign;

    @PlanningVariable(...)
    private boolean buy;

    private List<SpectrumRight> spectrumRights;
    ...
}
```

Within our constraint stream, I'm trying to aggregate all of the spectrum rights that are in the existing portfolio, combined with all of the spectrum rights conveyed in the licenses that get purchased in the auction, in order to compute some metrics on the improvement in portfolio spectrum rights.

```
private Constraint computeAggregatedSpectrum(ConstraintFactory factor) {
    return factory.from(AuctionLicense.class)
             .filter(AuctionLicense::isBuy)
             .map(AuctionLicense::getSpectrumRights)
             .union(SpectrumRights.class) /*<-from existingPortfolio in Solution*/
             .groupBy(toSortedSet())
             .map(MetricsCalculator::computeAggregatedSpectrumMhzPops)
             .reward(...);
}
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to append or union two ConstraintStreams together. Is there a stream operation that can be used? Or another workaround?

Comment: I fail to see why this should be necessary in your case. When you finally do `union()` with all `SpectrumRights` instances, you end up with all possible instances. Furthermore, you then put them in a sorted set, removing any advantage you might have gained in reordering the instances. What you give here appears to be the same as  `from(SpectrumRights).groupBy(toSortedSet())`.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an API gap.

Given a stream `s1` of about-to-be-bought spectrum rights `[A, B, C]` and a stream `s2` of existing spectrum rights `[D, E]`:

- a join() of both `s1.join(s2)` would give a stream of `[ {A,D}, {A,E}, {B,D}, {B,E}, {C,D}, {C,E} ]` which is not what you need.
- a concat(), union() or whatever we call it, doing `s1.union(s2)` would need to return `[A, B, C, D, E]`. This operation doesn't exist yet in the current ConstraintStreams API.

Let's create a jira.

Comment: Did this ever get created? If not is there a workaround? I've been trying to figure out a solution to the same issue.

Comment: No, not yet. Create a jira on the OptaPlanner project for it.

Comment: Done. For me the big issue is how complex it has become to do something that was simple in drl. I prefer constraint streams in general, but the transition has been painful, and for one project, impossible.

Answer (score 1):

fwiw this is now working in timefold 1.3.0
https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues/356